# How to open new tab link with command button with JSF dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

So, I have a command button that used to open a newtab link based on backing bean.

This code work perfectly    `context.execute("window.open('http://localhost:8080/AdrenaWeb/faces/test.xhtml);");`

but, when I want to change it 'hardcode link' into dynamic var pathInfo it can't work.

```
String pathInfo = test.xhtml;
context.execute("window.open('http://localhost:8080/AdrenaWeb/faces/'+pathInfo );");
```

Comment: what do you mean by _"can't work"_ ? Doe you mean 'does not work'?  What did you debug then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't concatenate the String correctly in your java code, you need to do it like this:

```
context.execute("window.open('http://localhost:8080/AdrenaWeb/faces/" + pathInfo + "');");
```